# Any blockchain bridge with API for BTC to WBTC conversion?

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency

I've been looking for any blockchain bridge that has an API as well as supports BTC to wBTC.

I've tried RenBridge, but that can only be used via their webApp. The path there would be, BTC to renBTC to wBTC (uniswap). But no API.

So, anyone aware of any such bridging service where i can get an API as well. Centralized bridge service is preferred but at this point, Decentralized would work too. API is a must.

I've explored the following list of bridges so far.

- xpolinate
- RenBridge
- zeroDao
- Obvious
- Binance Bridge

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question.
RenJs from RenProject can be used through an API to convert BTC to renBTC on etherium.

I must have missed this before as I mentioned looking at RenBridge.
https://renproject.github.io/ren-client-docs/ren-js/v3/tutorial/gateways